# How to add Combobox every time when i press button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanna build GUI and  there is a button which Combobox adds every time the button is pressed. but i cant find out how to figure or code this concept

And, is there any other Widget? or is there other way to build my concept??
please some one help me..

the main concept without using tkinter is Like this shown . i want this concept to be made in Tkinter.

[THIS IS WHAT I TRIED BUT WHENEVER I PRESS THE BUTTON, ALL COMBOBOX ADDED WORKS TOGETHER (which means when i change the list name, all combobox also changes..)]

```
def Plus_EXT():
    button_plus = Button(window3,justify = CENTER,command = Add_EXT, text= "+")
    button_plus.grid(row=0,column=0)

def Add_EXT():
    global Num
    window3.update()
    Num += 1
    CEList1 = [x for x in os.listdir(cur_dir) if ('CE' in x.upper()) and ('.rpt' in x)]
    RPT_EXT_file=ttk.Combobox(window3, values=CEList1,textvariable= EXT_String)
    RPT_EXT_file.grid(row=8+Num,column=1)
    RPT_EXT_file.set("FILE")
```

[MAIN CONCEPT WITHOUT USING TKINTER]

```
CE_Num= int(input("How Many EXTRA Chordae?: "))

User_File = input("Type the New File Name: ")

for Num_Of_EXT in range(CE_Num):
    RPT_EXT_file = input("Type the RPT of EXTRA CHORDAE: ") + ".rpt"
    EXTRA(User_File,RPT_EXT_file,Num_Of_EXT)
    EXTRA_PLT(User_File,Num_Of_EXT)
```

the output i want is { everytime i press the button a new Combobox is added in the frame with the lists which works separately.}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that all your Combobox widgets are linked with same textvariable called `EXT_String`.So when you change the value of one Combobox widget, it updates same value in all of them.

I would suggest to keep a list of such variables and index that list using `NUM` in your loop to assign the textvariable.

UPDATE:

Just an example based on limited code shared in `Add_EXT` method:

```
global var_list
var_list.append(IntVar()) #Or StringVar(), whatever you are using
RPT_EXT_file=ttk.Combobox(window3, values=CEList1,textvariable=var_list[-1])
```

Comment: @fateomamtte, I have updated the answer. I don't know where and how you are using `EXT_String`, so I hope you can manage accordingly.